# weird glitch when hovering over between 2 text items

Tags: html, css, hover, visual-glitch

I have a weird glitch in my website and I hope someone can help me. I created a list of items, each one with a header and some content. The items are closed when the website starts, and only the headers are visible. When you click on the header, the content is revealed/expanded.

When you hover over each header, the font family and style changes (See image attached). But here comes the problem: when I hover between 2 headers, they start glitching and repeatly changing. This is not supposed to happen. The glitch mostly happens when the mouse is hovering near 2 hedaders, so more or less in the line between them. Here is the website on CodePen, where the glitch also happens: https://codepen.io/Esteban-Barco/pen/JjwyNJZ

Here is my HTML Code for one of the items:

```css
h2 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  cursor: pointer;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.item-closed {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*text-transform: uppercase; */
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin: 2vh 0 2vh 0 2vh;
}

.item-closed:hover {
  font-family: 'Newsreader', Italic, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 4rem !important;
  color: #651EFB;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  cursor: url(assets/images/image01.jpg) pointer;
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
}

.item-closed:after {
  align-items: flex-end;
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "authentic-sans-130", serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #651EFB;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.item {
  padding: 0;
}

.item-open {
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

.item-open h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-family: 'authentic-sans-130'
}

.item:first-child {
  margin-top: 35vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="item item-closed" data-text="text" id="item02">
  <h2 class="white-text text" onclick="toggleInfo(); removeItemClosed()"><a href="#item02">The current picture Nr. 567 on my phone camera</a></h2>
  <div class="default-display toggle-info">

    <div class="form black">
      <div class="tag tag-left">
        <p>Found!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag tag-middle">
        <p>Reminded by Esteban Barco</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag tag-right">
        <p>I was cooking for over 15 people</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="invisible-box invisible-box-wrap">
      <img src="assets/images/image01.png" alt="memory" class="image image-margin-canvas" id="image02">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item item-closed" data-text="text" id="item02">
  <h2 class="white-text text" onclick="toggleInfo(); removeItemClosed()"><a href="#item02">The current picture Nr. 567 on my phone camera</a></h2>
  <div class="default-display toggle-info">

    <div class="form black">
      <div class="tag tag-left">
        <p>Found!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag tag-middle">
        <p>Reminded by Esteban Barco</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tag tag-right">
        <p>I was cooking for over 15 people</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="invisible-box invisible-box-wrap">
      <img src="assets/images/image01.png" alt="memory" class="image image-margin-canvas" id="image02">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting to see a normal text change behaviour when hovering, and the other headers should not interfere, so each one should change at a time.

Comment: Made your code into an executable snippet (and duplicated the HTML part, because if you say you have an issue with _two_ of those components, then an example with just one makes rather little sense) - but I am having a hard time telling where the actual problem with that is supposed to be now. Hovering from one header onto the other changes the style of both, sure - as to be expected. But that is hardly what I would call "glitching" here. Resp. I don't see how _else_ you would expect it to behave ...

Comment: @CBroe firs of all thank you! So my problem is for example when I leave the mouse right between 2 headers, they both start (or maybe just one of them, it happens way too fast) changing the style, and as I said it happens way too fast, as if it were a glitch. I wish I could embed a video here to show the behaviour.

Actually I just posted it on CodePen. The glitch also happens there. Here is the link
https://codepen.io/Esteban-Barco/pen/JjwyNJZ

Comment: _"when I leave the mouse right between 2 headers, they both start"_ - still not sure what you mean by that (not even clear what you actually consider a "header" here, when basically _all_ the lines of text appear to have this effect added), or where exactly I'd have to put my mouse to see two of them "glitch." That you see two of them changing at the same time, when you go from one to the other, and there is no space between them, is only logical - not sure how you could expect anything else.

Comment: @CBroe thank your for your reply : ) sadly I have no other means to show my problem. The glitch is still visible on CodePen, and as mentioned before the glitch happens when I slightly hover between 2 texts, or sometimes when I leave the mouse right between 2 of them. That should not happen.

Comment: All those text elements except for the "Ask me for" do not even _have_ any space between them, where I could put the mouse cursor, they all directly border each other. Sorry, but I really can't tell what the issue is supposed to be here.

Comment: @CBroe I think I was able to reproduce the issue, I took a [video](https://imgur.com/a/DtYRPOR) from the Codepen example

Comment: Okay, so it appears to depend on how the text breaks, at certain screen sizes. The issue stems from the fact that sometimes switching the font-style to italic makes a text that in normal style still fitted into one line, now a tiny bit wider, so that it breaks into two lines - moving everything that follows as well, and depending on what exactly the mouse cursor is, you might be hovering a different element then, without actually moving the cursor - which reverses the effect, and so you land in that "glitch" situation.

Comment: But I don't see an easy fix for this - you can't apply `white-space: pre` to force the text to stay in one single line, because you _need_ it to break into multiple lines depending on screen width.

Comment: @CBroe I am absolutely grateful for your patience and your help. I decided to kill off the idea of having 2 different fonts with different styles on hover, and sticked to having just one font, and made an underline style to it when hovering over. At least the website is now more consistent. Thank you!